# find php files from directory within directory

Tags: php

I have code for find php files from one directory.

```
$files = glob('./application/controllers/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Is there any way to find php files from directory within directory.

I mean, if there are some folders in controllers folder and inside those folders php files are there. then, how can I detect those files too.

Comment: [The RecursiveDirectoryIterator class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: `./application/controllers/*/*.php` Btw. using curly braces and `GLOB_BRACE` makes no sense in your example. (But it can, again, when you want to find .php files in the specified directory _and_ sub-directories at the same time, then you’d just have to specify the version without `/*/` as “alternative”.)

Comment: There is a fine example using [RecursiveIteratorIterator  in the manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php#91519)- so what are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nette Finder (https://packagist.org/packages/nette/finder) and do

```
$files = Finder::findFiles('*.php')->from('./application/controllers/');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo "$file\n";
}
```